# Windows 2012 installation, couldn't create partition or locate existing

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012, partition

I've seen this error all over the place for 2012 and 8 Windows' versions. I have tried multiple methods of getting around this issue to no avail.
Some methods I tried: Disk part from command prompt, reformatting and setting active and primary. Basic format within working Windows desktop. GParted format of drive and msdos partition table.

It's a sata drive connected directly to the motherboard of a Dell tower server.

It's interesting that Server installation can see the drive, format it, create a primary partition within the software installation but upon clicking Next it simply fails to continue. Install is coming from a DVD. There are no SD cards or USB drives connected and it is only listing my single SATA drive in the list. The only other thing I can think of is that I have a Perc s300 with drives attached to it; they don't show up in the list presumably because I don't have the drivers during the installation.

Why is 2012 so much more difficult to install on a drive? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to disconnect and remove the Perc RAID card (which is hardly a raid card, but what ever). Finally the installation could continue! As a side note, I tried 2008 and it reported the same issue, so it's not specific to 2012 installation. I actually removed all of the connections and then the card from the slot, physically. I'm sure there was a way to fiddle with this via software but I didn't see anything specific in the bios or perc config.